# Consulting my prolog file does not load its rules

Tags: prolog

I have 2 Prolog files.  1 containing facts ('facts.pl') and the other containing rules ('rules.pl').  When I consult facts.pl, it loads the all the facts.  However, when I consult rules.pl, Prolog just returns true.  I am able to query my facts, but I am unable to query my rules.

If I compile buffer the rules.pl file, the program works.  But I need it to work with just consulting it.  How do I fix this problem?

If it helps, here is the beginning of both files.
Here is the start of my rules.pl

```
/*To run this program, click 'complie buffer' in the 'compile' drop menu.
Jacob
04/26/2013
*/

mother(M, C) :- parent(M, C), female(M).        %M is the mother of C
father(F, C) :- parent(F, C), male(F).          %F is the father of C
spouse(M, F) :- married(M, F)|married(F, M).    %M is the wife of F or F is the husband of M
child(C, P) :- parent(P, C).
```

Here is the start of my facts.pl

```
/* Royal Family of England 1900-2000 */

female('Queen Victoria').
female('Princess Alexandra of Denmark').
female('Queen Mary').
female('Mrs Simpson').
```

There is of course many other facts in facts.pl.

Comment: This sounds fishy to me. How do you know it loads the facts, but not the rules? Show an `ls` (or `dir`, if it's Windows) inside the work directory, the content of the files, and the actual interaction with the Prolog interpreter.

Comment: When I query the facts in facts.pl, it gives the correct results.  When I query the rules in rules.pl, it gives me
"ERROR:  toplevel: Undefined procedure: child/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)"

Comment: This is what I get when I type ls in prolog
    *rules.pl, 
    facts.pl, 
    true.*

Comment: I get "ERROR: child/2: Undefined procedure: parent/2," which is true, there is no `parent/2` defined by your facts or your rules. If you really are getting a problem with child/2, I don't see how anybody is going to be able to solve it without physically looking over your shoulder and seeing what's wrong with your environment.

Comment: I have about 92 facts in facts.pl, my queries on the rules work when I compile buffer rules.pl @DanielLyons

Comment: I have no idea how you could create such a bizarre situation. You should get in-person help.